# How do ask a permission for open a gallery in android phones using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, gallery, imagepicker

I have using image_picker: ^0.8.4+11 for open a gallery. I need to ask a permission for open a gallery. In iOS it ask a permission to open a gallery but Android it did not ask a permission

I have tried like this in my AndroidManifest file

but it did not work to me. could you please any one can help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have tried like this:   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 1):

These permission are required to be added to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

//  Add these to android/grade.properties file.
android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true 

// Get from gallery
_getFromGallery() async {
   PickedFile pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
        maxWidth: 1800,
        maxHeight: 1800,
    );
    if (pickedFile != null) {
        File imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have already added but it does not ask a permission

Comment: I have already added those lines to android/gradle.properties and added compileSdkVersion 31 to build.gradle file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646085/how-to-request-and-check-permissions-in-flutter